# How to write proper rewrite rule for avoiding wrong url getting indexed

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have our most of the htaccess rules as below

```
RewriteRule page_a\.php page_main.php?param=alpha
```

As a result when a URL of the following form is fired, the page returns result
www.sitename.com/somethings..../page_a.php

We do not want such a request to be successfull as these creates wrong indexing.
Is there a way to ensure that this page executes only when the request is of the form
www.sitename.com/page_a.php

Could you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes make sure to line start/end anchors in your regex:

```
RewriteRule ^page_a\.php$ page_main.php?param=alpha [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `$`is line end, L is for last rule and QSA is for query string append. Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Is it a best practice to be followed while creating htaccess rewrites. I have just fixed this issue with one of the URL of the pattern as mentioned in my post. Apart from that we do have some other URL like www.sitename.com/a.html, www.sitename.com/b.php?a=b&c=d etc. Can I say that $ line end need to be used where urls are ending with .html and no QSF is required.Similarly line end $ and QSF is required where the pages are .php and having parameters. could you pls confirm

Comment: Yes it is always better to use start/end line anchors to make sure you don't match unwanted URI. Also `QSA` will still work with `$` in the end since Query string isn't matched in `RewriteRule`.

Comment: does this mean we should use QSA only when we know there are URL parameters ? If we do not use QSF, what will be there in the Right hand side , is it like [L]

Comment: No it means use QSA only when your rule is modifying query string (as is the case in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just force the match to be at the start of the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^/*page_a\.php page_main.php?param=alpha [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^/page_a\.php page_main.php?param=alpha
```

The `^` regexp metacharacter represents the start of the string, so this way you require the entire URL to match from the start. Its opposite is the `$` which matches the end of the string.